# How to make the input of a text field go red with the rest of the component in mui v5

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to achieve color consistency throughout the entire text field component and want it all to turn red simultaneously. However, it's not working as intended. Currently, only the underline turns red, not the value within the input field. I tried to target the input class but I  think I might have some syntax error..

```js
export const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)(({ theme }) => ({
  '.MuiInputBase-input': {
    fontWeight: 800,
  },
  '& .MuiInputBase-input::placeholder': {
    color: 'inherit',
    opacity: 0.7,
  },
  '& input:-webkit-autofill': {
    '-webkit-text-fill-color': 'white',
    '-webkit-background-clip': 'text',
    'background-color': 'transparent',
  },
  '& .MuiInput-input': {
    color: 'inherit',
    fontWeight: 800,
  },
  '& .label.Mui-focused': {
    color: 'inherit',
  },
  '& .MuiInputBase-root': {
    color: 'inherit',
    fontWeight: 800,
  },
  '& .MuiInput-underline:before': {
    color: 'inherit',
    borderBottom: '2px solid',
  },
  '& .MuiInput-underline:hover:before': {
    borderBottomColor: 'inherit',
    borderBottom: '2px solid',
  },
  '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
    borderBottomColor: 'inherit',
    borderBottom: '2px solid',
  },
  '& .MuiTypography-root': {
    fontWeight: 800,
    color: 'inherit',
  },
  '& .MuiFormLabel-root': {
    color: 'inherit',
    fontWeight: 800,
    marginTop: 4,
    marginLeft: 5,
    transform: 'translate(0, 7.3px) scale(1)',
  },
  '& .MuiInputAdornment-root': {
    color: 'inherit',
    fontWeight: 'inherit',
  },
  '& .MuiFormHelperText-root': {
    textAlign: 'center',
    lineHeight: 1,
    color: 'inherit',
    fontWeight: 'inherit',
  },
  '& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
    borderColor: theme.palette.grey[50],
    borderWidth: '2px',
  },
  '&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
    borderColor: theme.palette.grey[50],
    borderWidth: '2px',
  },
  '& .Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
    borderColor: theme.palette.grey[50],
    borderWidth: '2px',
  },
  '& .MuiInputLabel-root': {
    margin: 0,
    color: 'inherit',
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: 800,
  },
  '& .Mui-disabled': {
    fontWeight: 800,
    color: theme.palette.grey[700],
    borderBottom: 'none',
    '&:before': {
      borderBottomColor: theme.palette.grey[500],
      borderBottom: '2px solid',
    },
    '&:hover:before': {
      borderBottomColor: {
        borderBottomColor: theme.palette.grey[500],
        borderBottom: '2px solid',
      },
    },
  },
  '&.Mui-error .MuiInputBase-root .MuiInputBase-input': {
    color: theme.palette.error.main, // Change this to your desired error color
  },
}));
```